# Enviar botão como parâmetro na funcão disparada por click

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos, onclick

Tenho alguns botões que não possuem id. Ao clicar neles gostaria de enviá-los como parâmetro para a função disparada pelo click.

Gostaria de saber se a linguagem permite algo do tipo:

`button.addEventListener("click", function(this) {});`

Ou se vou precisar definir um id e pegar o botão dentro da função usando:

`document.getElementById();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode recuperar esse elemento utilizando o próprio evento, quando você registra um `listener` sua função recebe como parêmetro um objeto com os dados desse evento, sendo assim basta que você faça algo assim:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
   console.log(event.target)
});
```

Dessa forma você consegue capturar o elemento `button` que foi clicado.

Caso você precise recuperar todos os `buttons`, ai talvez seja interessante definir algum identificador como um `class` por exemplo, ai nesse caso você pode recupera-los dessa forma:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
   const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn")
});
```

Dessa forma você conseguiria recuperar todos os elementos `button` que possuem essa classe.

Answer (score 1):

Para ser mais acertivo, poderia usar o evento onclick dentro da sua TAG e enviar o This, assim ele retornará com certeza aquele botão clicado

```html
<button onclick="suafuncao(this)">Clique me<button>
```

e seu script

```js
   suafuncao(this) {
     console.log(this)
   }
```

Ou para ficar mais organizado, pode fazer chamar todos nos botões:

```js
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button')

for(i=0; i<buttons.length; i++){
 buttons[i].onclick = function() {
  console.log("clicado")
 }
}
```

Comment: Bom saber, então é possível usar o this. Vlw

Comment: Por nada, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Tentei utilizar desta forma e não funcionou. Fiz como o Gabriel José falou.